# Create groups of N items from a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

There is a list with many items. Below is just an example:

```
example = ['Ireland',
 '324',
 '437',
 'Germany',
 '376',
 '431',
 'Canada',
 '387',
 '231']
```

How to create a **tuple** with N items each, so it becomes:

```
[('Ireland', '324', '437'),
 ('Germany', '376', '431'),
 ('Canada', '387', '231')]
```

I am trying to find different ways to do that, to better understand the language.

I have done it so far with this:

```
[x for x in zip(*[iter(example)]*3)]
```

How else could that be done while using only built-in functions?

Comment: This looks good enough, i doubt you're going to get a more concise version out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
[tuple(example[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(example)-2, 3)]
```

However, if the list length is not a multiple of 3, items will be missed out.

As a side note, your answer can be shortened to

```py
list(zip(*[iter(example)]*3))
```

instead of using `[x for x in iter]`.

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension can help,

```
>>> example = ['Ireland',
...  '324',
...  '437',
...  'Germany',
...  '376',
...  '431',
...  'Canada',
...  '387',
...  '231']
>>> n=3
>>> [tuple(example[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(example), n)]
[('Ireland', '324', '437'), ('Germany', '376', '431'), ('Canada', '387', '231')]
```

If the length of the list is not a multiple of n, you will end up last tuple with less than n items. Quick hack is to fill the input list with some values to make it's length a multiple of n.